# Pass dictionaries in function as arguments

Tags: python, keyword-argument

Im trying to create a function that take unknown number of arguments (dictionaries) to merge them in one. Here is my sketch:

```
weight = {"sara": 60, "nick": 79, "sem": 78, "ida": 56, "kasia": 58, "slava": 95}
height = { "a" : 1, "b": 2, "c":3 }
width = {"u": "long", "q": 55, "qw": "erre", 30: "34"}
a = {10:20, 20:"a"}

def merge(**dict):
    new_dict = {}
    for x in dict:
        for a, b in x.items():
            new_dict[a] = b

    return new_dict

print(merge(weight, height, width, a))
```

And I got error:

```
TypeError: merge() takes 0 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Why?

Comment: Well, the error can be corrected by changing `merge(**dict)` to `merge(*dict)`. `merge(**dict)` means that `merge` takes an arbitrary number of _keyword_ arguments. `merge(*dict)` means that `merge` takes an arbitrary number of _positional_ arguments.

Comment: In line with what MrGeek is saying, you're using a kwarg here when you should be using positional arguments.

Comment: Please try not to use type names like `dict` as variable names.

Comment: Instead of writing `merge(weight, height, width, a)`, you can just write `{**weight, **height, **width, **a}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `def merge(**dict):` to `def merge(*dict):` and it is working. Avoid naming it `dict` since it is a keyword in python.

Comment: If i remember well dict is a class, and calling it with () is calling its constructor.

Answer (score 3):

***First note:** `dict` is a bad name for an argument as it is already the name of a type.*

When you use `**` in the argument list for a function it is slurping up any keyword arguments you haven't explicitly listed. Similarly, a parameter with a single `*` is slurping up any extra positional arguments not explicitly named.

Consider:

```
>>> def foo(bar, **baz): return (bar, baz)
... 
>>> foo(42, wooble=42)
(42, {'wooble': 42})
>>> foo(bar=42, wooble=42)
(42, {'wooble': 42})
>>> foo(bar=42, wooble=42, hello="world")
(42, {'wooble': 42, 'hello': 'world'})
>>>
```

If you wish to take any number of dictionaries as arguments, you'd use:

```
def merge(*dicts):
    ...
```

As `dicts` will now slurp up any number of dictionaries passed in.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass a `list` of `dict`s as a single argument you have to do this:

```
def foo(*dicts)
```

Anyway you SHOULDN'T name it `*dict`, since you are overwriting the `dict` class.

---

In `Python` you can pass all the arguments as a `list` with the `*` operator...

```
def foo(*args)
```

...and as a `dict` with the `**` operator

```
def bar(**kwargs)
```

For example:

```
>>> foo(1, 2, 3, 4) # args is accessible as a list [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> bar(arg1='hello', arg2='world') # kwargs is accessible as a dict {'arg1'='hello', 'arg2'='world'}
```

---

In your case you can edit the prototype of you function this way:

```
def merge(*dicts):
```